# Is Pokémon Bank still compatible with ORAS?

Tags: pokemon-omega-ruby-alpha-sapphire, pokemon-bank

I want go go back to my Alpha Sapphire game and catch the legendaries I missed out on. I had already transferred my Gen 4 Legendary Trio to my Pokémon Sun game. Since I caught them in Hoenn, I thought I would be able to transfer them back the Alpha Sapphire so I could catch Dialga, but unfortunately, I couldn't.

Before I reset my game and catch the trio all over again, I would like to know if I am able to store Pokémon I have in my Alpha Sapphire in the bank, reset my game, and still be able to transfer them back into my Alpha Sapphire. This way, I could use an existing team to speed the game up a bit, and hopefully get to catching the trio faster.

Am I able to  transfer Pokémon between saves, like this, or is this method a lost cause?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Pokémon Bank page on the official Sun and Moon site](https://www.pokemon-sunmoon.com/en-au/pokemon-bank/), once you use it to transfer a pokémon from gen 6 to gen 7, you won't be able to transfer it back to gen 6. It sounds like this is the problem you encountered.

If you keep your gen 6 pokémon in the bank and they don't touch a gen 7 game, they should be fine to transfer back into your reset Alpha Sapphire.

Answer (score -2):

You can still use Pokémon Bank on every game since B/W, but Pokémon from another save won't obey you unless you have the appropriate badges: Stone Badge for Pokémon up to level 20, Knuckle up to level 30, Dynamo up to 40, Heat up to 50, Balance up to 60, Feather up to 70, Mind up to 80 and Rain for all Pokémon.

Comment: true, but a little bit off topic

Comment: Yeah, didn't see the part where they already transferred forward.